# CoreData Relationship Use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, entity-relationship

Im new with CoreData and have a relatively good hold on it, except now Im starting to look at relationships and need a little help.

An issue in my app made me think about it, I have two entities, TableInfo and PersonInfo.

A table can have many people sit at it, but a person can only sit at one table. So I know it would be a one to many relationship in that respect and it makes real world sense as well.

Anyway, in my app, I add a table to my person, so I basically say, this persons sits at this table. However, how do I handle, if I then go and delete the table I have already given to a person?

I figured relationships might come into play here, but I have never worked with them before so its tricky for me to understand where to go here.

If anyone knows of any good tutorials which will help with this issue or details core data relationships, or you can help I would very much appreciate it, thanks, or let me know if Im barking up the wrong tree with relationships for this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good situation where you would use Core Data relationships.

The usual Apple Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html) will give you a good grasp of how it works.

In short, for a relationship you can specify a Delete Rule.
In your case, you would probably choose "Nullify". That means, if you delete the table, the table-property of your Person will become null, indicating that your person no longer sits on a table.

Edit: You could also specify "Cascade" which would delete the person together with the table (rather pointless, but slightly amusing thought). Or, you can specify "Deny", which will abort a deletion if at least one person still sits on the table.

Example:

Assume you have two entities, "TableInfo" and "PersonInfo". "PersonInfo" has a *relationship* called "table", "TableInfo" has a *relationship* called "persons". "table" is a to-one relationship with "TableInfo" as its target. "persons" is a to-many relationship with "PersonInfo" as its target.

Now set the "Inverse Relationship" of "persons" to "table". The "Inverse Relationship" of "table" will bet set to "persons" automatically.

If you let CoreData generate your model subclasses (you should!), you will end up with a class like this:

```
@interface TableInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *persons;
@end

@interface TableInfo (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPersonsObject:(PersonInfo *)value;
- (void)removePersonsObject:(PersonInfo *)value;
- (void)addPersons:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePersons:(NSSet *)values;
```

As you can see, CoreData automatically creates appropiate accessors for you. Just use them.

You can now do the following:

```
TableInfo* myTable = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TableInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

PersonInfo* myPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PersonInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[myTable addPersonsObject:myPerson];
NSLog(@"%@", myPerson.table); // will be your TableInfo object "myTable"
```

In short, please read the documentation I linked above, there are plenty of examples there and on the internet. Feel free to ask questions on SO, but for "basic" needs the tutorials on the internet will be more complete and helpful.

Comment: Ahh very useful. However, how do you add for example a person to a table? As person isn't an attribute of table and an entity can't be an attribute of an entity.

Comment: Just define the relationship and let CoreData create the classes for you. You can access relationships the same as attributes, i.e. you would be provided [TableInfo addPersonInfo:] and [PersonInfo setTableInfo:] etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far and sorry you'll have to bear with me. Things are becoming clear though. The core data usage in my app is based off that in Apples own CoreData Books example code. So the user for example can use the UINavigationViewController to hop through, select a guest, then edit the attributes of that guest, such as its name and table. With this relationship, do I treat the table attribute just as normal? But instead use the relationship name as the key? etc

Comment: Just som extra details. Say the user has selected someone on the list, and then they choose to edit their name, easy, new view, type name, save string into core data. However, if I want to assign a table to that person, I select to give them a table, new view, the user sees a list of the tables, selects one (I have that down, no issue there) then what? How am I supposed to use the relationship? This is what has me stumped.

Comment: Thanks! Its coming together in my head much better now and I'll go over the documentation again. One thing continues to stump me though, lets say I am creating my cells and I do this: `cell.textLabel.text = @"Table"; cell.detailTextLabel.text = person.tableName;` This displays the table name, a string in my core data model. How do I do this with a relationship? As Im chucking the idea of using a straight string out of the window and instead getting the table from its own entity. I can't do person.table.name, so a bit stuck. Last question I promise!

Comment: Assuming that the person's table is properly set (NSLog is your friend) and TableInfo has a property "name", and this property is also correctly set, you can indeed use `person.table.name`. From an accessor perspective, a relationship is basically no different than an attribute, except that it's "smart" with DeletionRules and InverseRelationships (assuming you're not doing some special overriding stuff etc.)

Comment: Ok thanks so much for all the help. I can't currently access anything through `person.table.nothingHereAtAll`. I have setup the relationship as suggested and let Xcode create the classes for my entities (they loo k just like you put in your example). This answer certainly covered what it needed to! If you do have any suggestions as to how to remedy this, let me know, otherwise not to worry and thanks a lot, you've helped me hugely.

Comment: You most likely haven't `#import "TableInfo.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at lecture 12 and the shutterbug example on how to setup relationships. He used a photographer to photos relation which is same as your table to people relation. The lecture might still be available on iTunesU under CS193P for fall or spring 2010-11.

Slides and example are available at this link.
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall